# я не понимаю что не так с кодом(недавно начал изучать java)

Tags: java, строки, scanner

я хочу чтобы код выдавал your car: , затем я ввожу audi, volkswagen или bmw, и в зависимости от ответа я получу какой либо ответ(good car!, better than mine! и т.д),
но если я ввожу название машины, к примеру audi, ничего не происходит. скорее всего проблема в сканнере, я просто не знаю как его написать нормально
КАК ЭТО СПРАВИТЬ ПОМОГИТЕ ПОЖАЛУЙСТА

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.String;
public class Main
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String z = "audi";
        String x = "volkswagen";
        String y = "bmw";
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("your car: ");
        String car_name = scan.nextLine(); 
        if (car_name == z) {
            System.out.println("Good car, man!");
        } else if (car_name == x) {
            System.out.println("Better than mine!");
        }
            else if (car_name == y) {
            System.out.println("That's good!");
        }


    }
  }
```

Comment: умоляю помогите

Comment: Судя по тому как сильно вы просите о помощи, вас держат в заложниках. Лучше обратитесь в полицию.

Answer (score 0):

Строки нужно сравнивать используя метод equals.

```
if (car_name.equals(z)) {
    System.out.println("Good car, man!");
} else if (car_name.equals(x)) {
    System.out.println("Better than mine!");
} else if (car_name.equals(y)) {
    System.out.println("That's good!");
}
```

Обратите внимание, что x, y, z и car_name — это разные объекты. Нужно сравнивать не их самих, а их содержимое (текст), что и делает метод equals.

Answer (score 0):

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("your car: ");
        String carName = scan.nextLine(); 
        switch(carName) {
            case "volkswagen":
                System.out.println("Better than mine!");
                break;
            case "bmw":
                System.out.println("That's good!");
                break;
            case "audi":
                System.out.println("Good car, man!");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```